# Trixbox: Pressing # causes calls to be placed on-hold

Tags: trixbox

We're using Trixbox Pro v2.0. When someone calls our office and presses the # key on their phone mid-conversation, the staff member is placed on hold (with hold music) while the caller is asked to enter an extension number by an American voice. They hear a dial-tone followed by the American voice saying "thats not a valid extension number please try again" shortly afterwards. The calls are then reconnected.

Does anyone know how I can turn off this # option? I think it's known as the Call Menu but I'm not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This should be in the feature codes list - Look under PBX Settings in the Trixbox web interface (I believe it's "in-call Attended Transfer" - the default is *2 IIRC)

Comment: I had a look in the web interface but could not find PBX Settings or an option for in-call attended transfer. I am looking at cp.trixbox.com (v4.2). Do you know exactly where the option is (or should be), or alternatively can I change a config file?

Comment: In Admin mode select PBX->PBX Settings from the top menu -- on the left under "Basic" should be "Feature Codes", & Transfers are under "Core" feature codes.  (If you don't have a PBX menu option you are in user mode -- there should be a "Switch" link in the upper right corner of the screen that will let you log in to the admin interface)

Comment: When you say Admin mode, do you mean simply log into cp.trixbox.com as our admin account? When I login, at the top all I see is AutoAnswer, Extensions, ACD / UAE, Reporting, Status, Options. There are sub-menus under each option but there is no PBX option.

Comment: @reado - I didn't notice the cp.trixbox.com bit in your previous comment -- it sounds like you're using the Fonality hosted Trixbox solution? If this is the case your best bet is Fonality's support (lightbulb icon on the bottom of cp.trixbox.com) - If it's possible to change this feature they can point you at the right spot.